# Can't instantiate a pointer within main window class

Tags: c++, qt

The compiler wont let me instanciate fileprocessor *p; in mainwindow.ccp but I am able to in any other class.

mainwindow.cpp

```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        fileprocessor *p;
        ui->setupUi(this);
        QObject::connect(ui->Open, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                         this,SLOT(on_action_Open_triggered()));
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
```

-mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

I am given **fileprocessor:undeclared identifier** and **p: undeclared identifier**

Comment: `I am given fileprocessor:undeclared identifier` - yes, since there is no type `fileprocessor` declared in your code

Comment: In which of the headers you're including is the type `fileprocessor` declared?

Comment: fileprocessor is a class, can't I create a new instance of a class within this class.

Comment: Of course you can but the compiler needs the definition of the class you want to instantiate. Simply add a `#include "fileprocessor.h"` your `mainwindow.cpp` or whatever the filename is where the class is defined

Comment: I have included the fileprocessor header file, I still get the same error. It works in other classes just not the mainwindow class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user4217633: Include `fileprocessor.h` in the `mainwindow.cpp`, **not** in `mainwindow.h`. There you need a forward declaration:

```
class fileprocessor; // Just this
```

You already have such a forward declaration, in fact:

```
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}
```